# Unable to save typed value or modified value to Kendo UI Combo Box in IE 9,10,11

Tags: internet-explorer, kendo-ui

Here is my issue, we are running web application using .Net MVC Web API with Kendo UI controls. In our grids for certain columns we have the type-ahead capability for various columns. For some reason in IE 9 - IE 11 when a user types a new value then clicks away or navigates to another field using mouse, the new value is lost and does not appear in the grid. Note that when we use the Enter or tab key the value instead of using the mouse, the value is saved.

Below I have a link to download a small demo that illustrates the issue. The problem occurs in Internet Explorer (versions 9 - 11) but not in Chrome or Firefox.

1. View the file grid-multiple-select-incell-editing.html in the browser
2. Click in the ProductName column to edit a value
3. Modify the value to any value that's not in the combo box
4. Click in some other cell

In Chrome and Firefox, the modified value is kept (as expected).  In Internet Explorer, the modified value is reset back to the original value.

In step 4, if you instead click entirely outside of the grid, the modified value is kept in all of the browsers including IE.

Demo: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53369650/BMW%20TOPS/ie-incell-editing-issue.zip

Comment: Note, we require multiple cell selection and editing in the application we are trying to solve this issue.

Comment: I have resolved this issue directly through Kendo UI by upgrading to the newest version. This is now working as expected in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue directly through Kendo UI by upgrading to the newest version (v2013.2.716). This is now working as expected in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mutliple selectable not working in ie

instead of selectable: "multiple, cell"  could you use selectable: "cell"

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        ..
                        ..
                        selectable: "cell",
                        ..
                        ..
                    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing to "cell" will not work for me. Our application requires "multiple" cell selection and edits for business reasons.